# Approaches to analyze shopping patterns

Tags: machine-learning

Say, you have data on customers' purchases. Data looks like

pID, date, town, price, place, item
100, 0203, True, 1.23, New York, Coca-Cola
100, 0203, True, 0.99, New York, bread
101, 0501,True, 1.43, Idaho, pen
102, 0502, False, 1.59, Nevada, eggs
102, 0502, False, 0.99, Nevada, Coca-Cola

And you have b illions of 
So, we have a set of purchase receipts. We need to figure out that $0.01 discount on soft drinks increases the sales volume by a factor of ten. That people purchase soft drinks with chips. That it is important to have a (lighter OR matches) if you sell cigarettes. 
What would be a good tool to classify such receipts?

Comment: What does pID mean? Purchase ID?

Comment: Yes, it is a purchase id to indicate purchases that come together.

Comment: I would recommended having a look at market basket analysis. It's a method used by retailers to identify items that are frequently bought together. You could use the pID to creates item sets - products bought at once time, the analysis will then tell you which items tend  to be purchased frequently together. This doesn't solve your problem but it might help you get started!